# Trying to fetch CPU, GPU, VPU usage and utilization through python

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, gpu, psutil

I'm trying to fetch CPU Usage, GPU Usage, VPU Usage using python basically I'm trying to create Performance tab from Task Manager. I have got little code from YouTube which basically fetches me CPU and Memory Usage .I want to add GPU Usage and VPU usage to this code.
Below is the mentioned Code.

```
import psutil
import time
import pynvml

pynvml.nvmlInit()
handle = pynvml.nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex(0)

def display_usage(cpu_usage, memory_usage, bars=50):
    cpu_percent = (cpu_usage/100.0)
    cpu_bar = '█' * int(cpu_percent * bars) + '-' * (bars - int(cpu_percent * bars))  
    #alt+219 num pad
    mem_percent = (memory_usage/100.0)
    mem_bar = '█' * int(mem_percent * bars) + '-' * (bars - int(mem_percent * bars))
    print(f"\rCPU USAGE: |{cpu_bar}| {cpu_usage:.2f}%  ", end="")
    print(f"MEM USAGE: |{mem_bar}| {memory_usage:.2f}%  ", end="\r")

while True:
    gpu_utilization = pynvml.nvmlDeviceGetUtilizationRates(handle).gpu
    display_usage(psutil.cpu_percent(), psutil.virtual_memory().percent, 30)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: How'd that work out for you?  What results did you get?  What did you hope to get?

Comment: it is fetching me real time cpu usage , im trying to get same npu usage/utilization using python